# How to create multiple column tables in ios application

Tags: ios, swift

I have started Swift recehtly.
I would like to create a table with 2 columns.
In detail, I would like to create balance sheet in finance.
The image of ui is as follows.

[image]

Also following condition have to satisfy the table.

・’Asset’ and ‘liabilities’ and ‘Net Asset’ and ‘Total’ cell should have same height
・other cells like ‘Cash:400’ should have same height but different height and design from ‘Asset’ cell

To realize that, what is the best practice?

My idea is creating two tableviews. one is for Asset and the other is for Liabilities.
The word ’Asset’ and ‘liabilities’ and ‘Net Asset’ and ‘Total’ cell should be developed as section in each table.
If there is other idea to make it easier. let me know please!

Comment: I suggest `UICollectionView`?

Comment: UICollectionView is more convenient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own code using UICollectionView to get the result you want. But I suggest you to use [DRCollectionViewTableLayout](https://github.com/darrarski/DRCollectionViewTableLayout-iOS), this will make your work lot easier and save your time.

Comment: Thanks. But let me confirm one more thing.

My understanding is UIcollectionview/DRcollectionViewTableLayout, the cell has to have same height per row.
So can UICollectionview/DRcollectionViewTableLayout express tables even if there is another height like 'Net Asset' in the row as the picture in question?